# Keep a software running

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, sandbox

I have a software that I don't want to close! I would like to sleep/resume it instead of close open.

I could use a VirtualBox to sleep/resume the system but I don't want to use this solution.

Any ideas? suggestions?

Comment: By definition, in order to run software, your computer needs to be running. Your question appears to be asking for a way to not do that... running the process on another machine, perhaps a rented server, would be the only way round that.

Comment: The main purpose of using a VirtualBox is to save the system status and resume my work on the software any time!

Comment: You mean a sleep/resume system, rather than "must be running 24/7"?

Comment: Yes sleep/resume the software instead of close/open

Comment: That would be VM territory, I think [but I'm no expert]. Could you edit your question to clarify this point, though - so then you would get appropriate answers.

Comment: Yes I could install a system on a VM and sleep/resume it but I don't want to use that solution! Question Edited.

Comment: Why not use a VM if this does what you want: is it a licensing issue? There are other VMs besides VirtualBox, especially VMware, which is free for non-commercial use. Any VM, though, will crash if the host OS crashes while the VM is running, but if you need to reboot the host OS you can suspend the VM, then do whatever you like with the host OS. If you don't use a VM, then you need to keep Windows running without ever making a cold start: only sleep or hibernate - unless you can modify the software to do its own suspend/resume, or (better) periodically save its state for auto-recovery.

Comment: Do you want your software to minimize to tray instead of closing?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, how often I have asked myself that same question.

Have the ability to save the state of a program so I can resume that state later exactly as it is without the need for a Virtual Machine.

Well, there isn't one.

There are 2 methods to achieve this.

## 1. Phyisical PC

The first method is to run the program on a physical pc and just keep the program running all the time. If you want to turn off the pc, then that pc has to be put into suspension. Of course, every once in a while, you will be forced to reboot the pc for updates.

Given that you likely want to be able to reboot your pc often without having this program closed, you can use a 2nd pc or server to run the program on, and use a Remote Desktop connection to control the program remotely.

## 2. Virtualization

The second option is to save the content of RAM. Now, the problem with this method is that when you load a program, its memory footprint is stored somewhere in memory. Lets say you have 16GB of ram, and the memory footprint of your program is 100mb Now, this 100mb can be at the start of the 16GB of ram, in the middle, at the end, or anywhere else. Because the memory addresses change every time you launch the program, it is going to be impossible to isolate the memory section that is used. Also, memory management can cause for unwanted problems if attempted. So in order to being able to still do it, the entire state of ram has to be saved, which is the full 16GB of RAM. This does not just store your program, but everything else that happens on your pc too.

The easiest way to do this is actually method 1, because when you suspend your computer, it makes sure the RAM portion is not changed the next time you use the computer. This is the same for standby and hibernation. Note that Hibernation does actually store the RAM to disk and then fully power off the pc.

If you want to save a smaller amount of RAM to disk and resume that, a Virtual Machine is what you need to use because then, you can have a VM that has a smaller footprint because you configure it as such.

Comment: It's the programming equivalent of owning a pair of shoes you never want to untie the laces of. Only real way is to never wear them... which is a waste of shoes ;-) Problem without a true solution, yet admirably stated.